# Android bluetooth client server

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm making a simple game on the similarity of the sapper. Now I want to add to my applications communicate via bluetooth. I found a few topics on the Internet, but I could not understand how it's done. Please help me understand how to make the bluetooth server-client communication

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this github repository https://github.com/polyclef/BluetoothChatMulti/tree/master/BluetoothChatMulti/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChatMulti

Comment: So hard) Do you have a easier example? Like a chat maybe?